# TSQL -- Strongly bind name to value on insert

Tags: sql

We have a database, that through a hiccup in a script, has one table that doesn't match the schema of it's sister database tables.  I have rearranged the table to match the schema of the other tables, but would like to strongly bind the name value pairs just in case the possibility arises of other databases having the same issue.  Currently I have the following and I am looking for an elegant way to do the same without throwing in a bunch of additional logic.

```
INSERT INTO Cars
SELECT CarName, CarModel, CarMake FROM SomeBigJoin
```

How can I spefically bind a Name/Value pair as I would if I did something like

```
INSERT INTO Cars (Name,Model,Make) VALUES (CarName, CarModel, CarMake)
```

...while preserving the SELECT statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Cars (Name, Model, Make)
 select CarName, CarModel, CarMake
  from SomeBigJoin
```

would do it.

Comment: Duh.  It's been one of those mornings.  Thanks!